# How can I plot (x,y,z) coordinates dynamically

Tags: c++, arrays, plot, coordinate, ros

My application obtains x,y,z coordinates like this:

x: -0.020941
y: -0.241276
z: 0.956
--------------
x: 0.0782352
y: -0.159108
z: 0.923
--------------
x: 0.0665857
y: -0.140757
z: 0.885
--------------
x: 0.0485952
y: -0.0859762
z: 0.785
--------------
x: 0.04494
y: -0.0477933
z: 0.749
--------------
x: -0.183467
y: 0.0505905
z: 0.64
--------------
x: -0.0519514
y: -0.0137343
z: 0.627
--------------
x: -0.0630648
y: -0.0206495
z: 0.586
--------------
x: -0.0774924
y: -0.0189667
z: 0.569
--------------
x: 0.0100971
y: -0.0100971
z: 0.558
--------------
x: 0.00456857
y: -0.0126905
z: 0.533
--------------
x: 0.000491429
y: -0.00835429
z: 0.516
--------------
x: -0.0227838
y: -0.01018
z: 0.509
--------------
x: -0.0222133
y: -0.00589333
z: 0.476
--------------
x: -0.10161
y: -0.00850476
z: 0.47
--------------
x: -0.0775429
y: 0.0162095
z: 0.46
--------------
x: -0.0897705
y: 0.0219057
z: 0.451
--------------

What I'm doing is every 3 seconds I'm taking the smallest z value from this stream and plotting it's position within a 2d array (using it's x and y position)

my question is how do I plot this result as I don't know what the maximum or minimum score could be and they're all double type, not int for the index. Is there a 'nice' way of plotting this?  I'd also like to be able to manipulate this data based on it's array index. e.g. find where data is clustering, etc.

Comment: It's a little hard for me to understand what your question is. Do you ask the way to find maximum or minimum score while the scores are all `double` type?

Comment: Not exactly, I want to add the points into a 2d array, but some of the points represent negative scores and others represent scores higher than 1. I need to find a way of adding them to an array so that they don't distort the results or cause errors.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to use the data in the 2d array for - simply storing it as is would not be an error in itself. You want to draw it to an image or something?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using the array to store the numbers for a period of time so I can find their average position. When a point has been there for 5 seconds it would be removed. points will be added continuously.

Comment: the points are added as coordinates, then by averaging them out I can find a center position for them all. But I don't know how to add them to this array dynamically, as the coordinates values aren't array index. They're just positions, which I need to 'map' or 'plot' into the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your issue is a result of having your heart set on using an array.  Using a vector would allow you to add grid points dynamically as well as averaging (and performing other calculations) whenever you wanted.

That being said, if you really want to use an array then like you have noticed you cannot use doubles and/or negative values as indices.  You could work out a system by adding an offset and multiplying your x,y values to get rounded integers and a center not at (0,0) but maybe at (2,2) or something instead but this would be really unwieldy and confusing.